# Where is class "com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler" definition?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

Everyone
  recently, I do code research with HttpUrlConnection module, when I find

```
   ... ...     
   // Fall back to a built-in stream handler if the user didn't supply one
    if (protocol.equals("file")) {
        streamHandler = new FileHandler();
    } else if (protocol.equals("ftp")) {
        streamHandler = new FtpHandler();
    } else if (protocol.equals("http")) {
        try {
            String name = "com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler";
            streamHandler = (URLStreamHandler) Class.forName(name).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    } else if (protocol.equals("https")) {
        try {
            String name = "com.android.okhttp.HttpsHandler";
            streamHandler = (URLStreamHandler) Class.forName(name).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    } else if (protocol.equals("jar")) {
    ... ...
```

Where is no Java which name is "com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler" or "com.android.okhttp.HttpsHandler",

So how & where Android load this class?

Comment: I gotta ask, what did you search for before you posted this question?

Comment: sorry for missing this info , i search this on http://androidxref.com/, but no usefull info i think. see http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/search?q=com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools

Answer (score 1):

[Question: Why PackageName is "com.android.okhttp" not "com.squareup.okhttp"? #2201](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2201)
The reason the package name is **com.android.okhttp** is because there are [jarjar rules](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/master/jarjar-rules.txt) which repackage it under that name.

Answer (score 0):

You can found [HttpHandler](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/54a6fb9990ddb2ab66d4afc79541a0801b1aaac9/android/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpHandler.java) at android googlesource.

Basically, com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler doesn't make sense, and It should be squareup.okhttp.HttpHandler, which extends URLStreamHandler and contains some method as openConnection() and getDefaultPort()